# In MySQL: selecting publications on keyword but including all keywords in results

Tags: mysql, sql

The publications table looks like this:

```
publications
============
id title etc ...
```

The keywords table looks like this:

```
keywords
========
id name etc ...
```

The keywords_relations table creates relations between publications and keywords, as foreign keys, where pid points to publications.id and kid points to keywords.id.

```
keyword_relations
=================
pid kid
```

In MySQL, I have constructed the following query:

```
SELECT publications.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(keywords.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS keywords
        FROM publications
        LEFT JOIN  keyword_relations
        INNER JOIN keywords
        ON keyword_relations.kid = keywords.id
        ON keyword_relations.pid = publications.id
        WHERE keywords.id = 1
        GROUP BY publications.id
        ORDER BY publications.date DESC;
```

I am selecting publications on keywords.id. However, in the results listing the "keywords" column only returns the selected keyword. I would like the "keywords" column to include all available keywords that result.

If I remove the WHERE line I get a listing where the "keywords" column includes all available keywords for that result.

How can I both select on a keyword, and include all keywords in the results?

Comment: Can you describer what your table structure look like?

Comment: Does that query really run? I'd expect syntax error.

Comment: @jarlh, There are a `*` but with `group` will got an error is pretty normal.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question Frank. The query runs very nicely on MySQL.

Comment: Huh.. the query does actually run, and produces expected results. Except for the keywords issue. :-) Edit: I'm running MySQL 5.7.22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause rather than `WHERE`:

```
SELECT p.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(k.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS keywords
FROM publications p LEFT JOIN
     keyword_relations kr
     ON kr.pid = p.id  INNER JOIN
     keywords k
     ON kr.kid = k.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(k.id = 1) > 0
ORDER BY p.date DESC;
```

Notes:

- The `HAVING` clause is counting the number of keywords that match the condition.  The `> 0` means that there is one.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `ON` clause should go immediately after the tables.  One purpose of `JOIN` syntax is to put the join conditions next to the table references, rather than far down in the query.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Thanks also for the explanation of the join syntax. I have been googling this query together. So it feels like it's held together with gaffa tape. Much appreciated! Edit: It works exactly as intended now.